# docker-machine error to create default machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm trying to use docker-machine and virtualbox inside a container.

The host:
Ubuntu 16.04

I installed in the host

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic virtualbox-dkms
```

The Dockerfile definition

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
ca-certificates \
curl \
software-properties-common \
--no-install-recommends \
build-essential && \
curl -sSL https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
virtualbox-5.0 \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Builded the image container

docker build -t myVirtualbox .

I started the container using

```
docker run -it -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv --privileged=true myVirtualbox bash
```

Inside the container I downloaded the docker-machine

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o docker-machine && chmod +x docker-machine
```

Then I ran

```
./docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox default
```

This is the error

```
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only  adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox  bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12  that is is supposed to fix this issue
The default lines below are for a sh/bash shell, you can specify the  shell you're using, with the --shell flag.
```

In the container I have the virtualBox version 5.0.26r108824

Comment: Getting this error on `openSUSE` as well with `5.1.4_SUSEr110228` -- did you have any luck since July with this?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan I stopped working on that, you are installing VB inside a container as well? I found that we need to install a lot of dependencies, maybe I can help you If I know what you are working on.

Comment: Oh woah! I'm not trying to use `VB` inside a container, that sounds intense :D I was just trying to use `docker-machine` to provision a container inside of a `VB` vm (the other way around)

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan have you consider to use Vagrant? Using a Docker as provider you can provision containers inside VB

Comment: Trying to avoid VB and Vagrant altogether. The only benefit i see to `docker-machine` is you get network addressable containers without port conflicts

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan maybe you are looking something like this? `docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url=file://`pwd`/boot2docker.iso mymachine`